# Stacking using boostrap Grid System

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a header using Bootstrap. I'm trying to make the desktop version spread out over the full 12 grid like so:

[image]

Then on the phone I'm wanting to having the two stack like shown below:

[image]

This is the way I've been trying to accomplish so far with bootstrap but I am not having much luck: Any feedback or suggestions appreciated!

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="background row">

   <div class="col-lg-1 col-xs-12">
   <p class="text-center">gb</p>
   </div>

    <div class="col-lg-1 col-xs-12">
   <p class="text-center">us</p>
   </div>

   <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12">
   <p class="text-center announce-something-h">ANNOUNCE SOMETHING HERE</p>
   </div>

   <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12">
   <p class="text-center announce-something-h">UK</p>
   </div>
```

Comment: `xs-12` isn't right. That would make each button container full-width for mobile. You'll need to look into [column reordering](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-column-ordering) since your desktop and mobile columns are in different sequences.

Comment: Thanks @isherwood - how would I go about doing that

Comment: Bootstrap 3 or 4?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just use floats and media queries:

```
.header{
  background-color:grey;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.header__left, .header__right, .header__message{
  padding:10px;
}
.header__left{
  float:left;
}
.header__right{
  float:right;
}
.header__message{
  text-align:center;
  background-color:red;
}

@media(max-width:767px){
  .header__message{
    clear:both;
  }
}

<header class="header">
  <div class="header__left">
    <a href="#" class="header__button">GB</a>
    <a href="" class="header__button">USD</a>
  </div>
  <div class="header__right">
    <a href="#" class="header__country-select">UK</a>
  </div>
  <div class="header__message">Announce Something here</div>
</header>
```

live example:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PdXBZR

Comment: This solution does not use the classes already built into bootstrap.

Comment: No it doesnt, i suppose you could use the float utility classes on the left and right elements if you want - whats your point?

Comment: What wheel would that be? What bootstrap classes accomplish the same thing, beyond the float utilities i already mentioned? Im not being snarky, i am genuinely interested in your answer.